# Precedence rule for serviceworker in case of two serviceworkers

Tags: service-worker

I am planning to have two service worker .But the Scope for one is subset of another's.

Ex: One is *'/'*

Other is *'/images'*

Now i am registering the two service workers from different places.
My doubt is when both serviceworkers are present and browser sends a request to */images* , then which serviceworker will intercept it , as it is in scope of both the serviceworker.

Does the browser gives precedence to the more specialized scope ?

Edit: This my code for registering two Service Worker.Now i want to register both Service Workers when first call is made to '/'.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerEndpoint1, { scope: serviceWorkerScope1 }).then(function (registration) {
            Log.Log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ' + registration.scope, "ServiceWorker1Installed", "ServiceWorkerInstalled");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            Log.Log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ' + err, "ServiceWorkerInstalled", "ServiceWorkerInstalled");
            });   

        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerEndpoint2, { scope: serviceWorkerScope2 }).then(function (registration) {
            Log.Log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ' + registration.scope, "ServiceWorker2Installed", "ServiceWorkerInstalled");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            Log.Log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ' + err, "ServiceWorker2Installed", "ServiceWorkerInstalled");
        });           
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both work but **only one is active per scope** so the browser gives preference to the most specific one. I leave you a setup to verify (although I tried it by myself):

Folder structure:

```
.
├── images
│   └── sw-images.js
├── index.html
└── sw.js
```

In ./images/sw-images.js:

```js
self.onfetch = event => {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('content') != -1)
    event.respondWith(new Response('Hi from images'));
};
```

In ./sw.js:

```js
self.onfetch = event => {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('content') != -1)
    event.respondWith(new Response('Hi from root'));
};
```

In index.html:

```html
<script>
  Promise.all([
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', { scope: '/'}),
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('images/sw-images.js', { scope: 'images/' })
  ])
  .then(() => console.log('All right!'))
  .catch(error => console.error(error)); 
</script>
<a href="content.html">./content.html</a>
<a href="images/content.html">./images/content.html</a>
```

Comment: I know it is weird but for me the the specific one is serving a generic url,It is like serviceworker registered for /image is intercepting /.what could be the reason?

Comment: Did you use this setup? Can I take a look to the code?

Comment: I have added my code in my question part , please have a look.What is happening now is, it is opening a new developers tab for the first registered SW(in chrome) and it is pausing on the first line.The second one is working fine.But the first one is not working.I have to manually click it to activate.

Comment: Maybe one of the service workers is not registering. You can see which sw is registered in chrome://serviceworker-internals/ in Chrome. Check there that both sw are registered. In case not, show us your service worker endpoints and scopes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when saying _manually clicking_, sorry. Can you explain?

Comment: I had to do several test cycles until I realized what **only one is active per scope** actually means.

I tried to implement 2 service workers for handling requests of a single page app
(A) for caching static files &
(B) for handling data API requests (having api/ in their URL).

However this won't work in the app. The app resides at the root and all XHR and fetch requests will be handled by the cache service worker. Only if I make the request via DOM (e.g. iframe or img) or from a file in the /api folder the API service worker actually kicks in.

I wonder who came up with that idea...

Comment: For details on my comment see my repo at https://github.com/valioDOTch/minimal-pwa

Comment: Here are further discussions about this in the W3C-repo:
https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/921 &
https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1085 .

So there's a reason why it was designed like this, but it's cumbersome to work with this in some cases. E.g. currently I implement a ExtJS SPA and intended to use the new SenchaCmd "progressive" config (which produces SW code by using the sw-precache library) while covering all API requests with a different SW. Now I have to find some odd workaround for this like overloading addEventListener in my SW or similar...